# How to count number of days it takes for a value to be matched or exceeded in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find out the number of days it takes for a certain value (in a different column) to be matched or exceeded.

For example, the close price (Column E) of a stock on January 2nd, 1962 was $50, I want to know the number of days it takes for five continuous close prices (their average) to either match the close price on January 2nd or exceed it.

Thanks!

Comment: Some sample data or a screenshot, plus the expected result, would be helpful here.

Comment: Make a helper column with the 5-day rolling average. Make another helper column that compares that average to the target, returning 1 for greater or equal and 0 otherwise, and then find the first match in that column.

Comment: BigBen - I don't want to sound stupid but I couldn't find out how to add files here with my question.

Comment: L. Scott Johnson - I tried that but instead went another way I found to be longer but easier.